# Running of mesh generator DistMesh under version Mathematica 13.2

Tags: bugs, finite-element-method, mesh, compatibility

I am trying to run the element mesh generator `DistMesh`from [FEMAddOns](https://github.com/WolframResearch/FEMAddOns) package by using version Mathematica 13.2 under Ubuntu 20.04.

```
Needs["FEMAddOns`"]
DistMesh[Disk[]]
```

and got the next messages:

[image]
[image]

and so on... I have tested all the others functions from `FEMAddOns` and they work properly with version 13.2. Previously I used `DistMesh` with version Mathematica 12.0 and there were no such problems. Thanks in advance for any advice for overcoming this issue.

Comment: Confirmed this is a bug, I'll try to update the code in the next few days. But pull requests are welcome of course.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update: The bug is fixed in [FEMAddOns](https://github.com/WolframResearch/FEMAddOns) version 1.4.6 and if you grab the latest version with

```
ResourceFunction["FEMAddOnsInstall"][]
```

things should behave normally.

---

This is a bug. As a quick work around try this:

```
Needs["FEMAddOns`"]

Clear[DistMesh`Private`greaterEqualZeroPosition]
DistMesh`Private`greaterEqualZeroPosition[th_] := 
  Flatten[SparseArray[1 - UnitStep[th]]["NonzeroPositions"]];

DistMesh[Disk[]]
```

I'll push a proper fix in the next few days. Sorry about that.

Comment: thanks a lot for support!

Comment: It was an excellent idea to implement DistMesh in Mathematica.